# Meaning of 'managing these risks to business continuity'

Tags: meaning

Please help me understand the meaning of the following sentence:

> **Managing these risks to business continuity** is the focus of this section of the manual.

I'm having trouble with the first part, does it mean 'managing risks **to maintain** business continuity'?

Comment: Hello @Koko and welcome to the site! You may find our sister site, [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com), helpful to what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is business jargon.  To understand it better, break the phrase down.

"business continuity" is a desirable thing.

"risks to (business continuity)" are bad - these are situations or events that could cause business continuity to fail.  "risks to something" can also be written as "risks that threaten something" or "risks that could damage or destroy something".

"managing these (risks to business continuity)" is how you go about controlling those bad things so that you can continue to have business continuity.

"managing risks" is a common term that encompasses perceiving risks, categorizing and measuring risks, and doing something to prevent them or deal with them.

"Managing these risks to business continuity is the focus of this section of the manual" could be re-written as:

> The focus of this section of the manual is how to manage the risks that threaten business continuity.